# java.lang.IllegalStateException with mediaPlayer

Tags: java, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, soundpool

I am building an educational app for children and I am using mediaplayer for the sound of letters and the alphabet song, but the app crashes sometimes when I call the .stop() function.

The Error massage is

> ```
> at android.media.MediaPlayer._stop (Native Method)
> at android.media.MediaPlayer.stop (MediaPlayer.java:1550)
> at com.alotaibi.alphabetapp.arabic_alph$onCreate$4.onClick (arabic_alph.kt:110)
> at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:6897)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:26101)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
> at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6944)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
> ```

and here is the function

```
play_abc.setOnClickListener {/// this fuction plays the sound of alphabet
        play_abc.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause)
        if(abcSongAra!=null) { // here i check if the song is playing then stop it 
            abcSongAra?.stop() /// the app crashes here but not always just sometimes 
            abcSongAra?.prepare()
        }
        if (active2 == 1) {
            abcPlayAra = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.playy)
            abcPlayAra?.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                abcPlayAra = null
                active2=1
            }
            abcPlayAra?.start()
            active2 = 2
            play_abc.startAnimation(anim)
            play_abc.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause)

        } else if (active2 == 2) {
            active2 = 1
            if(abcPlayAra!=null) {
                abcPlayAra?.stop()
                abcPlayAra?.prepare()
            }
            play_abc.startAnimation(anim)
            play_abc.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_pause)
        }
    }
```

Here is the whole code

```
package com.alotaibi.alphabetapp

import android.media.MediaPlayer
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.view.animation.Animation
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_arabic_alph.*
lateinit var mAdView_araAlph: AdView

class arabic_alph : AppCompatActivity() {

//song palyer
var abcSongAra:MediaPlayer?= MediaPlayer()
var abcPlayAra:MediaPlayer?= MediaPlayer()
var ls:MediaPlayer?= MediaPlayer()



//animation
var anim:Animation?=null

private lateinit var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_arabic_alph)

    MobileAds.initialize(this) {}
    mAdView_araAlph = findViewById(R.id.adView)
    val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
   mAdView_araAlph.loadAd(adRequest)



    mInterstitialAd = InterstitialAd(this)
    mInterstitialAd.adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-9266659982084890/2364898561"
   mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())






    anim=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.rotate)



    abcSongAra = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.songg)
    abcPlayAra = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.playy)
    ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ara1)
    ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
        mp.reset()
        mp.release()
        ls = null
    }
    ls!!.start()

    var active1 = 1
    var active2 = 1


    song.setOnClickListener {

        song.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause)
        if(abcPlayAra!=null) {
            abcPlayAra?.stop()
            abcPlayAra?.prepare()
        }




        if (active1 == 1) {
            abcSongAra = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.songg)
            abcSongAra?.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                abcSongAra = null
                active1=1
            }
            abcSongAra?.start()
            active1 = 2
            song.startAnimation(anim)
            song.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause)


        } else if (active1 == 2) {
            active1 = 1
            if(abcSongAra!=null) {
                abcSongAra?.stop()
                abcSongAra?.prepare()
            }



            song.startAnimation(anim)
            song.setImageResource(R.drawable.soonngg)
        }
    }
    play_abc.setOnClickListener {
        play_abc.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause)
        if(abcSongAra!=null) {
            abcSongAra?.stop()
            abcSongAra?.prepare()
        }



        if (active2 == 1) {
            abcPlayAra = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.playy)
            abcPlayAra?.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                abcPlayAra = null
                active2=1
            }
            abcPlayAra?.start()
            active2 = 2
            play_abc.startAnimation(anim)
            play_abc.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause)

        } else if (active2 == 2) {
            active2 = 1
            if(abcPlayAra!=null) {
                abcPlayAra?.stop()
                abcPlayAra?.prepare()
            }



            play_abc.startAnimation(anim)
            play_abc.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_pause)


        }
    }


}
fun letterSound(view: View) {
    anim=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.rotate)
    var choice = view
    when (choice.id) {
        R.id.h7a2 -> {


            h7a2.startAnimation(anim)
            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.h7a2)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()

        }
        R.id.jeem -> {

            jeem.startAnimation(anim)
            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jeem)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()            }
        R.id.tha2 -> {

            tha2.startAnimation(anim)
            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tha2)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()             }
        R.id.ta2 -> {

            ta2.startAnimation(anim)
            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ta2)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()             }
        R.id.ba2 -> {

            ba2.startAnimation(anim)
            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ba2)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()             }
        R.id.alf -> {

            alf.startAnimation(anim)
            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alf)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()             }
        R.id.seen -> {

            seen.startAnimation(anim)
            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.seen)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()             }
        R.id.zay -> {

            zay.startAnimation(anim)
            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.zay)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()             }
        R.id.ra2 -> {

            ra2.startAnimation(anim)
            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ra2)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()             }
        R.id.zal -> {

            zal.startAnimation(anim)
            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.zal)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()             }
        R.id.dal -> {

            dal.startAnimation(anim)
            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dal)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()             }
        R.id.kha2 -> {

            kha2.startAnimation(anim)
            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kha2)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()             }
        R.id.a3en -> {

            a3en.startAnimation(anim)
            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.eye)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()             }
        R.id.za2 -> {

            za2.startAnimation(anim)
            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.za2)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()             }
        R.id.t6a2 -> {

            t6a2.startAnimation(anim)
            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.t6a2)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()             }
        R.id.dad -> {

            dad.startAnimation(anim)
            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.dad)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()             }
        R.id.sad -> {

            sad.startAnimation(anim)
            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sad)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()             }
        R.id.sheen -> {

            sheen.startAnimation(anim)
            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sheen)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()             }
        R.id.meem -> {

            meem.startAnimation(anim)
            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.meem)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()             }
        R.id.lam -> {

            lam.startAnimation(anim)
            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.lam)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()             }
        R.id.kaf -> {

            kaf.startAnimation(anim)
            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kaf)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()             }
        R.id.k8af -> {

            k8af.startAnimation(anim)
            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.k8af)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()             }
        R.id.fa2 -> {

            fa2.startAnimation(anim)
            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fa2)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()             }
        R.id.kein -> {

            kein.startAnimation(anim)
            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kein)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()             }
        R.id.waw -> {

            waw.startAnimation(anim)
            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.waw)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()             }
        R.id.ha2 -> {

            ha2.startAnimation(anim)
            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ha2)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()             }
        R.id.ya2->
        {

            ya2.startAnimation(anim)
            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ya2)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()             }
        R.id.noon->
        {
            noon.startAnimation(anim)

            ls = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.noon)
            ls!!.setOnCompletionListener { mp ->
                mp.reset()
                mp.release()
                ls = null
            }
            ls!!.start()             }

    }
}


override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()

   if(abcPlayAra!=null) {
   abcPlayAra?.release()
}
    if(ls!=null) {
        ls?.release()
    }
    if(abcSongAra!=null) {
        abcSongAra?.release()
    }


        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded) {
            mInterstitialAd.show()
        }

}


}
```

Comment: Formatting, grammar and edited tags.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have right MediaPlayer lifecycle. MediaPlayer will throw IllegalStateException if your player is not init.

Provide full exception stacktrace.

Comment: i didnt understand , could you please explain more ??